# React redux passing event handler through connect & mapDispatchToProps vs. rendering child with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, redux, react-redux

Going through the react-redux docs, I'm trying to understand why the
[todo example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) uses `connect` and `mapDispatchToProps` vs why the [reddit example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) uses a more traditional render method & passing the dispatch through a handler as props to the child component. Is there a reason for this? I can only guess that it's because the former example has a container component correspond to only **one** presentational component whereas the latter example's container component contains **two** presentational components so it would not make sense to use connect (nor is it possible) on two components.

[todo example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) :

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)
```

[reddit example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html):

```
class App extends Component {
...
  handleChange(nextReddit) {
    this.props.dispatch(selectReddit(nextReddit))
  }
...

render() {
    ...
    return (
      <div>
        <Picker value={selectedReddit}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={[ 'reactjs', 'frontend' ]} />
        <p>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly okay to pass `dispatch` to your component unless you don't want your component to misuse the `dispatch` function and dispatch actions that are not supposed to be dispatched from that component!

If you want to limit your component, you don't want to pass `dispatch` directly to the component. You'll want to pass specific action creators through `mapDispatchToProps`.

I think it boils down to coding standards, really. If you decide to be strict on your components and not allow them to directly dispatch any action, you can use `mapDispatchToProps` to pass only specific action creators.

**Bonus:** In the first example, you're passing `(id) => dispatch(toggleTodo(id))` function to your component. Try using `bindActionCreators` from [redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) instead of manually creating that function! Good luck.

**UPDATE**

```
export const dataLoadRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: 'DATA_LOAD_REQUEST',
  }
}
```

In your `Component.js` file, you need to import two things.

```
import { dataLoadRequest } from 'actions.js';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Component extends React.Component{
  ...
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.actions.dataLoadRequest();
  }
  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(dataLoadRequest, dispatch)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Component);
```

Comment: For your Bonus tip, how exactly would you rewrite the `mapDispatchToProps` function to utilise `bindActionCreators`?

Comment: @jeevcat See updated answer. Please note that it's not tested. I just typed that in on my mobile app. Hope it helps.